# how to deal with ® in url for urllib2.urlopen?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-unicode, urlopen

I received a url: https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/citrix-xenapp®-75-desktop-virtualization-solutions; it is from BeautifulSoup.

```
url=u'https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/citrix-xenapp\xae-75-desktop-virtualization-solutions'
```

I want to feed back into urllib2.urlopen again.

```
import urllib2
source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

The error I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 43: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Thus, I tried:

```
source = urllib2.urlopen(url.encode("utf-8")).read()
```

It got page source, however it is different from what from the original url.

```
originalUrl = 'https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/citrix-xenapp®-75-desktop-virtualization-solutions'
originalSource = urllib2.urlopen(originalUrl).read()
originalSource == source
```

The result is False. Is there any idea to fix this url? How to convert u'\xae' into original `®`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs must be valid bytestring, with non-ASCII codepoints encoded correctly. You'll need to *encode to UTF-8, then url quote* the path of your URL:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import urlparse

originalUrl = u'https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/citrix-xenapp\xae-75-desktop-virtualization-solutions'
parsed_link = urlparse.urlsplit(originalUrl.encode('utf8'))
parsed_link = parsed_link._replace(path=urllib.quote(parsed_link.path))
encoded_link = parsed_link.geturl()
source = urllib2.urlopen(encoded_link).read()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2 
>>> import urlparse
>>> originalUrl = u'https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/citrix-xenapp\xae-75-desktop-virtualization-solutions'
>>> parsed_link = urlparse.urlsplit(originalUrl.encode('utf8'))
>>> parsed_link = parsed_link._replace(path=urllib.quote(parsed_link.path))
>>> encoded_link = parsed_link.geturl()
>>> encoded_link
'https://www.packtpub.com/virtualization-and-cloud/citrix-xenapp%C2%AE-75-desktop-virtualization-solutions'
>>> source = urllib2.urlopen(encoded_link).read()
>>> len(source)
68758
```

Comment: Is there any other easy way to deal with the whole URLs not just URL.path?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; if you try to apply `urllib.quote` to the whole URL then the wrong things are encoded (like the colons).

Comment: @Martijin, Thanks. You already answered my question. Just use urllib.quote to encode URL.path.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. I can pass it `http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Солнечная_система` without problems.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Provided you used a UTF8-encoded *bytestring* and not a Unicode string, it **may** work, depending on the server. Wikipedia supports sending URLs encoded as UTF-8 without proper URL quoting. This is over and above the requirements, you cannot count on all servers doing this.