# python urllib url encoding error

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, urllib

I'm trying to process the following html via urllib / BeautifulSoup

```
<a href="/citizen-home/council-and-democracy/finance-and-funding/financial-statements-budgets-and-variance-reports/expenditure-over-gbp-500/expenditure-over-£500-2011-12.html" class="internal-link">Expenditure over £500 2011-12</a>
```

The '£' character is causing the trouble, so I'm trying to clean up the url like this:

```
cleanUrl = urllib.quote_plus(link).encode('utf-8')
print cleanUrl
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py:1268: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

I've tried `urllib.quote()`, `.encode('Latin-1')` and `urlencode()` without a result. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I can't make sense of the error, as I'm not trying to compare anything.

> Correct code ported from Martijn's previous answer

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import urlparse

link = block.a['href']

parsed_link = urlparse.urlsplit(link.encode('utf8'))
parsed_link = parsed_link._replace(path=urllib.quote(parsed_link.path))
encoded_link = parsed_link.geturl()
html = urllib2.urlopen(pageUrl)
```

Comment: Can you please give us the **full** traceback of the error, not just the exception message?

Comment: Does this work instead? `cleanUrl = urllib.quote_plus(link.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: See [how to deal with ® in url for urllib2.urlopen?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26615374) for proper URL encoding handling.

Comment: Specifically: *You'll need to encode to UTF-8, then url quote the path of your URL*. You reversed those steps, and used the wrong `quote` function (drop the `_plus` part).

Comment: Thanks Martijn (again). Your original answer didn't show up in any of my searches, perhaps due to its very specific title.